# Deleted cell appears at the end of tableView list

Tags: swift, uitableview, timer

I have a request that update array (append there a new instance if it exist) of new incoming message

```
 @objc
    private func loadNewThread() {

        func refreshThreads(newThreads: [ThreadModel]) {

            var oldThreads: [ThreadModel] = self.threads
            var updatedThreads: [ThreadModel] = []

            for new in newThreads {
                updatedThreads.append(new)
                if let index = oldThreads.firstIndex(where: { $0.threadId == new.threadId }) {
                    oldThreads.remove(at: index)
                }
            }

            updatedThreads.append(contentsOf: oldThreads)
            self.threads = updatedThreads

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.updateEmptyState()
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }

        messageService.getThreads(searchText: searchBar.text?.lowercased(), page: 0) { (result) in
            switch result {

            case .value(let newThreads):
                refreshThreads(newThreads: newThreads)

            case .error(let errors):
                self.handleErrors(errors: errors)
            }
        }
    }
```

I update it in viewDidLoad by Timer every 5 sec

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 5.0, repeats: true, block: { [weak self] (timer) in
            guard let self = self else {
                timer.invalidate()
                return
            }
            self.loadNewThread()
        })        
    }
```

I am removing element from array and row respectively by element index

```
if let index = self.threads.firstIndex(where: { $0.threadId == thread.threadId  }) {
                                    let cellIndex = self.threads.firstIndex(where: { $0.threadId == thread.threadId  })

                                    self.threads.remove(at: index)

                                    if let cellIndex = cellIndex {
                                            self.tableView.beginUpdates()
                                            self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath.init(row: cellIndex, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
                                            self.tableView.endUpdates()
                                            self.animateLayout()
                                    }
```

But after deleting, the deleted cell appears at the end of the tableView list. 
I suppose that the request to delete element fulfills after the request to append to the array
How should I make my cell disappear?

Comment: As you are reloading `tableView` after updating `threads` with new list so you don't need to delete rows after `self.threads.remove(at: index)`. Can you show how `refreshThreads` is called?

Comment: @Kamran I missed the end of loadNewThread() function
I call refreshThread there

 messageService.getThreads(searchText: searchBar.text?.lowercased(), page: 0) { (result) in
            switch result {
                
            case .value(let newThreads):
                refreshThreads(newThreads: newThreads)
                
            case .error(let errors):
                self.handleErrors(errors: errors)
            }
        }

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58303300/edit) your question and add the related code.

Comment: @Kamran sure, already

Comment: Currently, you are only avoiding duplication but all the new and old objects will be there in the list. If you want to remove the items that  exists in both lists then change for-loop as `if let index = oldThreads.firstIndex(where: { $0.threadId == new.threadId }) {
                    oldThreads.remove(at: index) } else { updatedThreads.append(new) }`